# populate a dropdownlist according to the values selected from a different dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to populate my `dropdownlist` with room numbers according to the roomtype selected from other `dropdownlist`. But on selecting the roomtype from the `dropdown` the values in other `dropdown` get duplicated each time. Here is the sql table and the program.

```
Room num, Room type,  Cost,    Status
A1        AC          223     Av
B2        Non Ac      180     Av

public partial class customer_reservation : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newdb"].ConnectionString;
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   { 
   }
   protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

    string rval = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    con.Open();
    string qry = "select Roomnum from room where rtype=@rval and rstatus like 'AV'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry,con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rval",rval);
    SqlDataReader rd1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (rd1.HasRows)
        {
            while (rd1.Read())
            {
                DropDownList2.Items.Add(rd1[0].ToString());
            }
        }
        con.Close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
```

beaning to your function `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged`

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
    string rval = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    con.Open();
    string qry = "select Roomnum from room where rtype=@rval and rstatus like 'AV'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry,con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rval",rval);
    SqlDataReader rd1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (rd1.HasRows)
    {
        while (rd1.Read())
        {
                DropDownList2.Items.Add(rd1[0].ToString());
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this is to clear the item collection in the second dropdownlist and then start populating it.

Simple `DropDownList2.Items.Clear()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

on selected index changed of first drop down list

bind the second list to its data source.

```
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(true) // your check condition
    {
     //clear previous values using .Clear()
     dropdownlist2.Items.Clear()
     //bind the second dropdownlist to new options
     //or add options
    }
}
```